# Matrix value gets overwritten - Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, global

I am writing a program in Python. I have a 2-D matrix implementation using lists that I have declared outside the scope  of all the function. The idea is to store in the matrix values computed from subsequent function calls. My code is something like this:

```
database=[[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)] #2-D matrix

def func(data,x,y):
   #manipulate the list data and then store it in database[x][y]
   data[1]+=1
   database[x][y]=data

   print("database[0][0]={}, database[1][1]={}".format(database[0][0], database[1][1]))
   del data[:]

def main():
   data=['one',1]
   func(data,0,0)

   data=['two',2]
   func(data,1,1)

if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

At the end, i am getting database[0][0] as something different. I am wondering why index [0][0] does not have ['one', 2]! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried running your code and it works fine (no overwriting).

Comment: I have not posted the actual code, since it involves storing packets that come into the network interface, and then storing a few fields into a list. Its kind of complex. Should I post the code here?

Comment: A simplification of the code is better, but only if you can recreate the problem. Otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: I agree, and I am sorry I could not recreate the problem. I am working on it and I shall post in asap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `func` when you do `del data[:]` you delete the object that the local argument `data` is pointing to. So even though you've stored a reference to it in the database it's gone.

You can either:

- remove the delete statement, local variables will be discarded anyways, there is no need for this
- Use `database[x][y]=list(data)` instead to make a copy of data as a new object

Comment: Actually, in my implementation, data is a global list, and has to get cleared once it has been assigned to a specific index in the matrix. Hence I have to use the del operator. But by using list(data) solved my problem! Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, glad it helped anyways then.